# The relationship between Hell Class and hypometric (and Homunculus) weapons in Alastair Reynolds's novels

Tags: alastair-reynolds, revelation-space

In Alastair Reynolds's *Revelation Space* series of books, there is a cache of mysterious weapons called "Cache Weapons" or "Hell Class weapons". They work in different ways, but they all seem to have some spacetime-bending properties.

The origin of these weapons is mysterious, but eventually partially revealed:

> It is eventually revealed that the Conjoiner faction of humans created these weapons at some point in the past, based on blueprints/information from the future, through Exordium. According to Wikipedia (although I don't remember this from the books itself), "The Many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics is assumed, and allows participants to form neural links with their past, future, and alternate selves" through Exordium.

There is another class of powerful weapons later in the series, called hypometric weapons.

> Hypometric weaponry is said to be a highly advanced class of weapons that also bend spacetime, usually discovered only by races after one or two million years of spacefaring civilization. It is discovered stored inside neutron stars that work as computers by parallelizing the past, present and future versions of itself.

So my question is this:

**Are the Cache Weapons built from the same technology as the hypometric weapons, gleamed from the (or a) future?**

And as a related bonus question: In Reynolds's *House of Suns*, a stand-alone novel not connected with *Revelation Space* that takes place millions of years in the future, there is a class of weapons called "Homunculus weapons", that also work by bending spacetime. If we assume the "many-worlds interpretation", is it possible that the Homunculus weapons are also the same technology as the Cache/hypometric weapons, from one possible future of the *Revelation Space* universe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it's possible, but I don't think it's likely. As I recall, the homonculus weapons left a lingering 'scar' on the fabric of space-time where they were used, I don't recall any similar effect from the use of any of the cache weapons nor the hypometric weapons. Also, I *think* the time frames are too mismatched for them to be alternate versions via the many worlds hypothesis, I might be mistaken on this point though In the short story "Galactic North", the last date given us 40,000 AD, by which point the Greenfly machines have completely overtaken the galaxy, not the millions of years as given in House of Suns.

The cache weapons designs come from humanity's future via the conjoiner program Exordium, while the hypometric weapons are derived from designs left by extinct alien cultures.

Regarding the cache weapons, *Absolution Gap*, page 458:

> We cannot underestimate the cache weapons,” Remontoire said. “They were a gift from the future. Until they have been exhaustively tested, we cannot assume that they are inferior to anything Aura has given us.

Regarding the hypometric weapons, *Absolution Gap*, page 479:

> “Then where did this technology come from?”
>   “The dead. The collective memories of countless extinct cultures, gathered together in the neutron-crust matrix of the Hades computer."

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some evidence to back this up?

Comment: From Wikipedia: The smallest of the weapons seem to have been considerably more powerful than conventional space-borne weapons, and at least one is deemed capable of destroying a planet-sized object from a distance exceeding 100 AU...the most basic cache weapons appear to be radical extensions of otherwise conventional principles, such as relativistic projectile weapons with antimatter or neutronium ammunition and gamma-ray lasers. Others, however, make use of gravity wave effects and other complex phenomena, with certain weapons even containing microscopic black holes.

Comment: The hypometric weapon is an alien weapon, manufactured using technology acquired from the huge reservoir of alien knowledge stored inside an enormous distributed computer system disguised as neutron stars and (possibly) other astronomical objects. Hypometric weaponry is said to be highly advanced, usually only by races after one or two million years of spacefaring civilization.

Comment: Lastly, the hominculus weapon, from Wikipedia:
"There was a vicious attack on the reunion world; an ambush in which the majority of the Gentian Line was wiped out... the attackers used the supposedly long-vanished 'Homunculus' weapons – monstrous spacetime-bending weapons that were created ages ago, but were ordered to be destroyed by another Line."
Being that it says these weapons were created "ages" ago, I suppose they have a better chance of being an alternate version of a cache weapon, perhaps in a continuum where the Greenfly machines were defeated or never created?

Comment: Regarding the cache weapons: Redemption Ark, pp 503-04
Thirty-three weapons were present, no two of them alike... She had tested very few of them in any meaningful sense. Indeed, those she had known most about were the ones that were now lost. Some of the remaining weapons, she was certain, could not even be tested without wasting the one opportunity that existed to use them.

Comment: I'll get the House of Suns quotes when I can ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer so far. The reason I thought the hypometric weapons could perhaps be from the future as well, like the cache weapons, was the fact that the neutron star Hades (in which they were discovered) worked as a computer by parallelizing the past, present and future versions of itself (as revealed in _Revelation Space_), but your quote from _Absolution Gap_ makes it clear that they are from the past.

Comment: (_House of Suns_ taking place in an alternate future of the _Revelation Space_ universe (where the Greenfly never destroyed the galaxy, exactly) is obviously just a fan theory of mine, not supported in the source material, except perhaps if the Homunculus weapons actually are the hypometric weapons or the cache weapons (the Conjoiners don't need to have existed in this timeline; Primordium can tap into alternate timelines, so someone else can have made the weapons from their blueprints).

Comment: No problem! I think I have a copy of House of Suns in paperback floating around, I'll try and find it tomorrow. (So easy to search relevant terms in ebooks though lol)

Comment: Pretty sure that it would be the cache weapons and not hypometric- the hypometric weapons basically just take chunks of things clean out of existence, I remember homonculus described as leaving glowing scars on the fabric of space-time after their use. Will update when I have more.

Comment: Oops – Exordium, not Primordium :P And thanks!